# How to delete a folder that is "too long for the destination folder"

Tags: windows-7, eclipse

I tried to import a project with Eclipse but it ran forever and then I got an out or memory error.  Now I know why . . . it created a seemingly infinite number of "Task Manager" projects for some reason.

I tried to delete with the command line and even 7-Zip as suggested in other questions but nothing is working.  Any ideas?  And I tried to install "Unlocker" which I've used before but Security Essentials blocked it because of "TrojanClicker" from eBay_shortcuts_1016_new.exe (even though I unchecked the install of the eBay Shortcuts . . . something is amiss!).  I'm thinking I should create a separate question just about Unlocker.

In 7-Zip here is how deep I could go before I gave up . . . who knows how long this could go!  I renamed the folder "deleteme" so I could try the import again as I'm supposed to be working on Android development, now messing with deleting files.

C:\Users\Sheldon\Desktop\deleteme\Week_1\01 Task Manager\01 Task Manager\01 Task Manager\01 Task Manager\01 Task Manager\01 Task Manager\01 Task Manager\01 Task Manager\01 Task Manager\01 Task Manager\01 Task Manager\01 Task Manager\01 Task Manager\01 Task Manager\01 Task Manager\01 Task Manager\01 Task Manager\01 Task Manager\01 Task Manager\01 Task Manager\01 Task Manager\01 Task Manager\01 Task Manager\01 Task Manager\01 Task Manager\01 Task Manager\01 Task Manager\01 Task Manager\01 Task Manager\01 Task Manager\01 Task Manager\01 Task Manager\01 Task Manager\01 Task Manager\01 Task Manager\01 Task Manager\01 Task Manager\01 Task Manager\01 Task Manager\01 Task Manager\01 Task Manager\01 Task Manager\01 Task Manager\01 Task Manager\01 Task Manager\01 Task Manager\01 Task Manager\01 Task Manager\01 Task Manager\01 Task Manager\01 Task Manager\01 Task Manager\01 Task Manager\01 Task Manager\01 Task Manager\01 Task Manager\01 Task Manager\01 Task Manager\

Comment: Did you try to run a `chkdsk` on the disk, in case the filesystem is corrupted, causing the recursive directory?

Comment: Does chkdsk do anything in Windows 7?  Anyway, so far I was able to use robocopy (as suggested by a friend) to MOVE to the folder to a thumb drive (like this robocopy c:\users\sheldon\desktop\deleteme f:\ /MOVE /E) and from there I can just format the drive.  Not happy about that solution but at least it's been removed from my desktop. Not giving up yet!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

[Delete Doctor](http://www.diskcleaners.com/#deletedr) that let you you delete with short DOS name or UNC name

or

[DelinvFiles](http://www.purgeie.com/delinv/) same as delete doctor, but can scan the drive for invalid file names and from my experience it was successful where delete doctor wasn't. (But it's a shareware: 26.95$)

Comment: Looks like Delete Doctor is only for files, not folders.

Comment: try to drop the directory to the program

Comment: I tired to drop the folder into Delete Doctor but that didn't work either so I tried DelinvFiles and that worked!  Not exactly user friendly and it's not free but it did the job . . . but I gotta believe there is another way.

Answer (score 3):

What command did you use on the command line?

I've always had luck with:

```
rmdir /s /q "C:\Users\Sheldon\Desktop\deleteme"
```

Comment: I tried that but I get "The path <really long path> is too long."